# How to save specification and body of all the packages using oracle sql developer?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

How to save specification and body of all the packages, table, views DDL using oracle sql developer?

Answer (score 1):

Tools - Database Export

[Here's how to unload to files for say, adding to Source Control.](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2018/10/unloading-an-oracle-schema-to-script-files-for-source-control/)

[image]

And when it finishes...

[image]